# Change woocommerce checkout page form labels

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I change the label "Your Order" to "Your Items" in WooCommerce checkout page. I dont need to change any fields, just the name of the form categories. Also is it possible to remove the number in front of the label?

[image]

Comment: You need to override the `checkout/form-checkout.php` template. See [WooCommerce template overrides](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change file `woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php`

around line number 55

Change `<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>`

Your Order to Your Item

```
<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your Item', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

Thanks

Comment: how might I do this with a hook?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the text by altering the following code in **wp-content/themes/yourselectedtheme/inc/woocommerce/template-tags.php**

```
if( ! function_exists( 'unicase_review_wrapper_start' ) ) {
function unicase_review_wrapper_start() {
    ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                <?php
                    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder' ) && WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) {
                            ?>
                            <span>5</span>
                            <?php
                    } elseif ( is_user_logged_in() && WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) {
                            ?>
                            <span>2</span>
                            <?php
                    } else{
                        ?>
                        <span>2</span>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <?php esc_html_e('YOUR ITEM (**************)' , 'unicase'); ?></a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
        <div class="panel-body">
    <?php
}
```

}